# MoPub: TransformException - ZipException: duplicated entry when building on gradle

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, mopub

I'm trying to integrate MoPub into my app.

I imported the sdk into my app:

```
compile('com.mopub.sdk.android:mopub:4.4.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

But an error is returned when I tried to build it.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqq$zza.class

I have imported the `com.google.android.gms` llibrary into my app:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

So I thought I would exclude them from the sdk:

```
compile('com.mopub.sdk.android:mopub:4.4.1@aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

Still doesn't work.

Then I tried to remove transitive:

```
compile('com.mopub.sdk.android:mopub:4.4.1@aar')
```

Still doesn't work.

How do I get this MoPub sdk to integrate successfully into my android app?

Answer (score 3):

Actually I found the answer.

I'm trying to use the facebook audience network sdk and that sdk was the one that caused the conflict - doing this in the facebook audience network sdk caused the app to compile again.

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```