# Duplicate Entry Error - Dependancy and Project Module Confliction - Android

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, speech-to-text, cloudant

First of all. Below is the error that I am getting.

[image: ERROR IMG-1]

[image: ERROR IMG-2]

Now, What I am doing is like below....

I am integrating **Speech To Text** service of IBM. I have founded a demo [HERE!](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk)

I am also using another two Services of IBM named **Personality Insights** and **Cloudant Database**.

I have successfully integrated **Speech To Text** example. But When I integrate **Personality Insights** and **Cloudant Database** it gives me above **error.**

**WHAT I HAVE IDENTIFIED:**

- In STT demo there is a module called **speech-android-wrapper**.
- Which I have included to my app and added a line to *build.gradle** file like `compile project(':speech-android-wrapper')`.
- For **Cloudant Database** service I have dependency like `compile group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-sync-datastore-android', version: 'latest.release'`.
- When I comment **Cloudant Database** dependency. It won't give me above error.
- So, Some where these two dependencies are being conflicts.

Below is my Application's build.gradle file.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.stt_int.android01.sttdemofour"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    // ... other project repositories
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile project(':speech-android-wrapper')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    /*compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }*/
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:2.6.0'
    compile group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-sync-datastore-android', version: 'latest.release'
}
```

Below is **speech-android-wrapper** module's build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/java_websocket.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jna.jar')
}
```

I have try to exclude **ByteOrderMark.class** class using below code but I can not get desire outcome.

`android {
    packagingOptions { 
        exclude 'org/apache/commons/io/ByteOrderMark.class'
    }
}`

Any help will be **very very very** appreciated. Thanks!!

**Update-1: Dated: 28.03.2016**

I have tried like below from two links suggested by **@Nikolay Shmyrev** but none of links worked for me.

From 1st link.
`dependencies {
    compile files('libs/java_websocket.jar')
    //compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    compile files('libs/jna.jar')
}`

From 2nd link.
`dependencies {
    compile files('libs/java_websocket.jar')
    //compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons.io'
    }
    compile files('libs/jna.jar')
}`
I have removed `commons-io-2.4.jar` file from libs folder of **speech-android-wrapper** module.

**Update-2: Dated: 29.03.2016**

I have tried below too.

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile project(':speech-android-wrapper')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    /*compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }*/
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:2.6.0'
    compile(group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-sync-datastore-android', version: 'latest.release') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache', module: 'commons-io'
    }
}`

Below also..

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile project(':speech-android-wrapper')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    /*compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }*/
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:2.6.0'
    compile(group: 'com.cloudant', name: 'cloudant-sync-datastore-android', version: 'latest.release') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons.io'
    }
}`

to my project's build.gradle file. While I have changed my project's build.gradle file, build.gradle file of **speech-android-wrapper**  look like below.

`dependencies {
    compile files('libs/java_websocket.jar')
    //compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile files('libs/jna.jar')
}`

But nothing works for me.

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450238/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-with-spring-framework, exclude and exclude-module might be an option, but not in packagingOptions, you need to use them in dependency section (compile)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163756/mopub-transformexception-zipexception-duplicated-entry-when-building-on-grad

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Please, See updated answers.

Comment: You need to add exclude part to com.cloudant compile dependency, not to commons.

Comment: See the **Update-2**.@NikolayShmyrev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, as one can exclude some group my following line.

`configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'commons-io'
}`

I have added above line error disappears.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that it can work.

The issue happens because you are **adding the same class** (`org/apache/commons/io/ByteOrderMark.class`) **twice**.

If you checking the pom file of the `com.cloudant:cloudant-sync-datastore-android` library you will find this dependency:

```
commons-io:commons-io:2.4
```

In your speech-android-wrapper module you can:

- remove the `commons-io-2.4.jar` from the libs folder
- change the dependencies in the build.gradle removing the line `compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')` and adding `compile commons-io:commons-io:2.4`

Comment: Not worked for me. Thanks for answer.@Gabriele Mariotti